# XAMPP - mysql and phpmyadmin not displaying images

Tags: mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, xampp

I've installed XAMP and everything was working perfectly but every time I write this on "httpd.conf":

```
Options FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI

RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|mp4)$ - [F]
```

this happens on phpmyadmin (attached image), I can't access the tables and I can't figure out why. Any help?

[phpmyadmin image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnVtm.png)

```
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-04-01 12:15:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-04-01 12:15:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-04-01 12:15:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-04-01 12:15:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-04-01 12:15:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-04-01 12:15:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-04-01 12:15:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-04-01 12:15:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence number 0 in the system tablespace does not match the log sequence number 47116 in the ib_logfiles!
2020-04-01 12:15:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-04-01 12:15:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2020-04-01 12:15:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-04-01 12:15:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-04-01 12:15:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-04-01 12:15:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-04-01 12:15:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 47116; transaction id 9
2020-04-01 12:15:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-04-01 12:15:19 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-04-01 12:15:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200401 12:15:19
2020-04-01 12:15:19 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
saction id 299
2020-04-01 11:57:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-04-01 11:57:20 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-04-01 11:57:20 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2020-04-01 11:57:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200401 11:57:20
```

EDIT:
phpmyadmin error:
[phpmyadmin error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfEwa.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no mod_rewrite expert, but it appears to me as if you are deliberately blocking .gif files in your RewriteRule, which explains why the icons look very strange. What is it you're trying to accomplish with that line?

About the second error, it seems you may have configured the phpMyAdmin [advanced features](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#phpmyadmin-configuration-storage) (with the `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb']` directive, for instance) and either don't have or have removed the database or table used by phpMyAdmin for this. The easiest way to resolve this is to edit `config.inc.php`, remove that line (or comment it out) and start up phpMyAdmin again. Once connected, you can create the proper table structure from the `create_tables.sql` file in the 'sql' directory, or leave the functionality disabled.

There is a zero configuration option for using the advanced functionality; if you really don't have any reference in your phpMyAdmin tables it could be the autoconf taking over. Try logging in with private mode or from another browser (which would bypass local cookies) and see if that works better (if so, just clear your cookies, phpMyAdmin cookies start with `pma`).